# Primereact - how could I style a button to make it look like a Panel or PanelMenu (Accordion)

Tags: css, reactjs, accordion, primereact

so imagine a code akin to this:

```js
"use client";

import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { PanelMenu } from "primereact/panelmenu";

const DashboardsPage = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      label: "New",
      items: [
        {
          label: "Project",
        },
        {
          label: "Other",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-column">
      <Button>My Panel Header wannabe button</Button>
      <PanelMenu model={items} className=" w-full md:w-25rem text-sm" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardsPage;
```

What would be the exact steps I should take formatting wise to make the `<Button />` look exactly like a `<PanelMenu />` header item (i.e. look like the "New" entry).

I have tried dabbling in the classes a bit but I couldn't figure it out.

Thank you very much in advance

P.S. I have tried using an extra entry in `items` without any children but it does display an empty space and toggles the class to the `expanded` one. If you think that a solution with some formatting lies to that direction, that answer could also (probably) work. Ideally though, a solution using a button would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging around I found the following which probably gets the job done:

```js
      <div className="p-component p-panelmenu  w-full md:w-25rem text-sm">
        <div className="p-panelmenu-panel">
          <div className="p-component p-panelmenu-header">
            <a className="p-panelmenu-header-link" href="#">
              <span className="p-menuitem-text">My "button"</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This sequence of controls and classes gets the job done. Essentially I had to copy the *exact* hierarchy of components that Primereact creates.

My only gripe is that this is highly dependent on the library version (at the moment of this writing, 9.6.0).

Hopefully this helps someone.

Thanks a lot.